# Calculating rolling beta in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I am trying to calculating a rolling beta between two Series in Pandas.

My understanding is that to get the beta, I need to get the covariance matrix and then divide the cells (0, 1) by (1, 1)

So I created a function:

```
def calc_beta (A, B) :

    covariance = np.cov (A, B)     
    beta = covariance[0, 1] / covariance[1, 1]

    return beta
```

If I just wanted to run it for the entire series, I would do:

`calc_beta(A, B)`

But I'm not sure how to do that on a rolling basis, I tried `A.rolling(10).apply(calc_beta, raw=False, B)` unsuccessfully.

Then I just tried calculating the cov matrix on a rolling basis, which I can do:

```
A = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1,101,50))
B = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1,101,50))

df = pd.DataFrame([A, B]).transpose()
df.rolling(10).cov(df, pairwise=True)
```

Now I have a covariance matrix but how do I perform the beta calc, i.e. `(covariance[0,1]/covariance[1,1])` on a rolling basis (and then get the mean).

Comment: Could you please share a sample of the data you wish to perform the operation on? That would help to give you an aswer that is usable for you.

Answer (score 2):

It might not be the best answer (read, the most compact) but Ithink this could do the trick. You were actually on the right track to begin with. So, assume you have the two series you gave and make them into a df

```
A = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1,101,50))
B = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1,101,50))
df = pd.concat([A, B], axis=1)
```

Define the beta and the rolling in the following way:

```
def calc_beta(df):
    np_array = df.values
    s = np_array[:,0] 
    m = np_array[:,1]

    covariance = np.cov(s,m) 
    beta = covariance[0,1]/covariance[1,1]
    return beta

def rolling(df, period, function , min_periods=None):
    if min_periods is None:
        min_periods = period
    result = pd.Series(np.nan, index=df.index)

    for i in range(1, len(df)+1):
        df2 = df.iloc[max(i-period, 0):i,:] #I edited here
        if len(df2) >= min_periods:
            idx = df2.index[-1]
            result[idx] = function(df2)
    return result
```

And do the following:

```
calc_beta(df)
```

which return `0.15350171576854774`

and

```
rolling(df, 12,calc_beta, min_periods=None)
```

(Of course, you can choose any period)
which gives

```
0          NaN
1          NaN
2          NaN
3          NaN
4          NaN
5          NaN
6          NaN
7          NaN
8          NaN
9          NaN
10         NaN
11    0.034478
12    0.019883
13   -0.093483
14    0.140603
15    0.137694
16   -0.004115
17   -0.144355
18   -0.079803
19   -0.023759
20    0.099539
21    0.186670
22    0.199526
23    0.113457
24    0.152232
25    0.149928
26    0.079760
27    0.032097
28    0.056294
29    0.070176
30    0.076560
31    0.013778
32    0.080279
33    0.058864
34    0.006916
35    0.303566
36    0.133580
37    0.238668
38    0.312243
39    0.406835
40    0.337503
41    0.370470
42    0.237132
43    0.253779
44    0.160348
45    0.103425
46    0.261430
47    0.130407
48    0.314028
49    0.322890
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

so I appreciate the answer @Serge but I felt like I could do it in a slightly cleaner way. This is what I've come up with which works for me. Let me know if you have any comments on it. Thanks again.

```
A = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1,101,50))
B = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1,101,50))

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : A, 'B' : B})
df.rolling(10).cov(df, pairwise=True).drop(['A'], axis=1) \
                        .unstack(1) \
                        .droplevel(0, axis=1) \
                        .apply(lambda row: row['A'] / row['B'], axis=1) \
                        .mean()
```

Comment: why .mean() at the end?  Don't you want a series?

Comment: no I just wanted a single value, but you could leave that out and get the rolling series